# Undo bisect tool?

Tags: knife-tool, bisect

First time using blender and experimenting with ref to manual and YouTube. Haven’t been able to find out if it is possible to clear/delete a bisect. I’ve been able to alt click to highlight the bisect vertices introduced but then dissolving them also creates gaps in my model. I suspect I’m making a simple error. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hi :). Could you please add some screenshots to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Hi. I'll be able to see tomorrow if I still have that file. I am learning in test files and may have deleted it. Will post if I have the relevant example, if not I'll probably close this request and read the manual more closely. Thanks